# Can I use "neither ... nor ..." like this?

Tags: neither-nor

I came across this sentence:

> They can **neither** read **nor** write, **nor** can they comprehend such concepts.

[The link to this sentence (1st definition of **"nor"**, the last example)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nor)

I'm wondering if I can use **"neither ... nor ..."** like this:

> They can **neither** read, **nor** can they comprehend such concepts.

Or this is only correct like this? :

> They can **neither** read **nor** comprehend such concepts.

(I'm asking if after "They can **neither** read", the clause "**nor** can they comprehend such concepts" is correct as well as the phrase "**nor** comprehend such concepts")

Comment: Yes, _nor_ can be repeated in parallel structures. _Neither fish, nor fowl, nor meat, nor egg_

Comment: Ok, but I'm asking if after "They can neither read", the clause "nor can they comprehend such concepts" is correct as well as the phrase "nor comprehend such concepts"

Comment: Yes, they're both correct.

Comment: Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using "nor" in two ways.

> **nor** *conjunction* ([Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nor))
> 1 Used before the second or further of two or more alternatives (the first being introduced by a negative such as “neither” or “not”) to indicate that they are each untrue or each do not happen.
> ‘they were neither cheap nor convenient’
> 2 Used to introduce a further negative statement.
> ‘the struggle did not end, nor was it any less diminished’

The first clause in the sentence you came across uses definition 1: "neither ... nor ...".

The second clause treats the first clause as a negative statement and introduces a second negative statement: " nor ".

With your first suggestion "they can neither read, nor ...", the first clause is arguably incomplete, and *nor* is used in the sense of definition 2 to introduce a second negative clause. The sentence reads a little awkwardly if patterned after the original. It parses better if we consider "such concepts" to be ellipsed from the first clause - "they can neither read [such concepts] nor can they comprehend such concepts". That is, the assertion is that they can't read "such concepts", rather than a blanket statement about their general reading ability.

Your final example is a straightforward sentence that uses just the sense of definition 1.

Comment: Ok, so the first sentence that I suggested is incorrect. So if I say, for example: "He neither answered them, nor did he look at them." it's also incorrect and the correct sentence would be "He neither answered them nor looked at them", right?

Comment: @AlexFrt Yes, I'd agree, at least as far as strict grammar is concerned (except I'd use 'grammatical' instead of 'correct'). But because both quotes in your comment convey your intent, you might get away with it by citing poetic license.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @AlexFrt You're welcome.